# How to display user input multiplication table

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I am completely new to the coding world and would appreciate any help or guidance with this, please do tell if i could also improve my phrasing of the question or anything of that sort.

I had an assignment to produce a multiplication table using while loops in python which i did below:

```
print(end='\t')
a = 1
while a <= 10:
     print(a, end='\t')
     a += 1
b = 1
while b <= 10:
     print('')
     print(b, end='\t')
     c = 1
     while c <= 10:
          print(b*c, end='\t')
          c += 1
     b += 1
```

I was then wondering how to change it so that the program only shows the multiplication table for the chosen number 1-10 by the user. My problem is i don´t exactly know where to place the a = input() and b = input(). Appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You already have the logic in place.
Where you currently assign `a` and `b`, insert `input` statements for the upper limits.  Call them `a_limit` and `b_limit`, or perhaps `max_a` and `max_b`

```
max_a = int(input("How many columns do you want?"))
a = 1
while a <= 10:   # Practice for you: what do you need to change here to use max_a?  :-)
```

In the long run, I strongly recommend that you learn to use the `for` loop.  It will simplify your iteration a *lot*.

Comment: Right, Thank you!!! I wasn´t properly changing the while statement, once again thanks for the help :)))